# Error when trying to run an executable on a Linux system

Tags: linux

I am getting an error when trying to run an executable on a Linux system.

I wrote simple application which includes the library located at `/usr/local/lib` and the header files at `/usr/local/include`.

It was compiled as below;  it generated the executable.

```
 gcc -c gd-client.c -I/usr/local/include/dbus-1.0/dbus -L/usr/local/lib/ -o gd-client
```

But when I try to run the executable, it gives me the error shown below.

```
 cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

1. It was compiled using `gcc` and linked with actual path for both library and header files. Does it matter where the executable is located when I run it?
   I also tried  to place it under `/usr/local/bin/` but I am
   still getting same error.
2. As it was compiled and and is executing on the same machine, the OS and the  cpu architecture remains the same. It should not complain.

Can anyone tell what else might be wrong?

Edited:
the output of `file /bin/sh gd-client`:

```
 /bin/sh:      symbolic link to dash
 gd-client: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not 
 stripped

 $ file /bin/dash
 /bin/dash: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), 

 dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for

 GNU/Linux 2.6.32, 
 BuildID[sha1]=504637666875a5d526ef51acfe601c99efc99114, stripped
 $ /bin/ls
 gd-client  gd-client.c

 $ file /bin/dash gd-client
  /bin/dash:    ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1   
 (SYSV),         dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-
 x86-64.so.2,      for GNU/Linux 2.6.32,
  BuildID[sha1]=504637666875a5d526ef51acfe601c99efc99114, stripped
  gd-client: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not   
  stripped


    $ gcc -v
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=gcc
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
    Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
    Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-   kgversion='Ubuntu           5.3.1-14ubuntu2' --with-     bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs  --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --
    program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --   enable- clocale=gnu 
            --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-
            java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-
            amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --
            with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 5.3.1 20160413 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2)
```

Comment: The format of the executable isn't correct for the system.  Either you're not running the program you thought, or you're compiling it with options that mean it cannot run on your o/s.  Try running `file /bin/sh gd-client`; it will likely give you radically different answers about the type of file.  It is surprising, the behaviour you are seeing, but there will be a reason.  You may need to identify the Linux distribution and version that you're using; likewise the version of GCC.  And maybe adding `-v` (verbose) to the command line would be revealing.

Comment: Rerun the output for `file /bin/dash` (symlinks don't count for this — it is the executable that matters; `/bin/ls` instead of a shell would be OK too); the important information is the file type.  Are you expecting 64-bit code?  Presumably yes; the libraries were linked OK.  (In my previous comment, that's meant to be `gcc -v …`)

Comment: How are you executing the program?  From a shell command line, or some other how?  I haven't yet managed to persuade Bash (on Mac OS X) to give an 'exec format error', but I have gotten it from a trivial little C program executing other files with `exec*()` functions.

Comment: shell command line as below:                                                      ./gd-client  also tried just    gd-client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcc -c` doesn't generate executables; it generates object files. Remove the `-c` if you want an executable.

Comment: Of course — I was blinded and overlooked the obvious!  (And caught off-guard by not seeing 'object' in the output of `file` for the object file.)

Comment: That's it.  when compiled without -c option the executable runs without error.